# What XNA based 3D terrain and physics libraries exist?

Tags: c#, xna, physics

I'm planning on creating a game that contains a landscape with objects on it. The landscape will be defined using a heightfield, and the objects will move about on top of, and fly over the terrain. If you've ever played the old games [Marble Madness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marble_Madness) and [Virus/Zarch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarch), that's the kind of complexity and style I'm trying to create.

I've seen various physics engines on the Internet, and a few tutorials about how to render heightfields as terrain, but they either lack documentation or seem overly complex for what I need.

All I need is a way to draw a heightfield, place 3D objects on it and then make them roll down the hills, or fly around in the sky. I don't mind making my own code to do this, so any relevant tutorials would be good too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a more complete list, Xbox, Zune and Windows...

- [Farseer](http://www.codeplex.com/FarseerPhysics) - 2d only.
- [JigLibX](http://www.codeplex.com/JigLibX)
- [Bullet](http://bulletphysics.com/)

  - [BulletX](http://www.codeplex.com/xnadevru/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Managed%20Bullet%20Physics%20Library&referringTitle=Home)
  - [XBAP](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2007/04/24/xbap-3d-physics-source/)
- [Oops! 3D Physics Framework](http:///)
- [Bepu physics](http://www.bepu-games.com/BEPUphysics/)
- [Jello Physics](http://walaber.com/index.php?action=showitem&id=16)
- [Physics2D.Net](http://physics2d.googlepages.com/)

Windows Only...

- [PhysX](http://www.ageia.com/)

  - [MS Robotics Studio wrapper](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/robotics/default.aspx)
  - [PhysXdotNet Wrapper](http://code.google.com/p/physxdotnet/)
- [ODE (Open Dyamics Engine)](http://ode.org/)

  - [XPA (XNA Physics lib)](http://www.codeplex.com/xnadevru/Wiki/View.aspx?title=XNA%20Physics%20API%20%28XPA%29&referringTitle=Home)
- [Newton Game Dynamics](http://www.newtondynamics.com/)

  - [Newton Physics Port to XNA](http://www.tamedtornado.com/devblog/?p=58)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for more of a tutorial rather than a full-blown solution, have you checked the collision series at [the XNA creators site](http://creators.xna.com)?

Specifically, [Collision Series 5: Heightmap Collision with Normals](http://creators.xna.com/en-us/sample/collision3dheightmapnormals) sounds like exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Newton Game Dynamics](http://www.newtondynamics.com/), there is a [port of their physics engine](http://www.tamedtornado.com/devblog/?p=58) for XNA. The only caveat is that it only works under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Matali Physics Engine. Matali Physics is a physics engine for XNA.
[home page](http://www.mataliphysics.com)